# A set of bijections

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Let $A$ is a (possibly infinite) set.

Let $G$ is a group of functions (more precisely, bijections) on $A$ with function composition.

How to call such a group?

- a group of permutations of $A$;
- a group of bijections on $A$;
- whatever.

Comment: I think that the usual notation is permutations, but the other two are also appropriate ;)

Comment: Also the usual way to write the first two sentences is "Let A *be* a..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's typical to say:

> "$G$ is a [permutation group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) on $A$".

If we do a Google Scholar search for `"G is a permutation group on"` (in quotes), it comes up with numerous respectable examples of this phrase being used.

Answer (score -1):

This group G is commonly called "the symmetric group on A", especially if A is finite.  A shorthand notation is $S_A$.

Comment: Porton's group $G$ is a subgroup of $S_A$, not necessarily the whole group.

Comment: You are correct!  I apologize for reading too hastily.